# Button with 9-Patch background not wrapping content

Tags: android, button, size, custom-controls

OK I have a Button which uses as its background a selector. I set the width and height to wrap_content. The content is some text I set. I'm expecting the button to be sized around the text like a native button but the button is huge , basically looks as big as its source image. The button image is a nine patch image and the button xml is inside a relative layout. What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/holo_btn" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/holo_btn" />
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/holo_btn" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/holo_btn" />
</selector>



<Button android:id="@+id/btnTaskPriorityLow" 
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingSmallButton" android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingSmallButton"
            android:text="@string/strTaskPriorityLow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewCalColor"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewPriority"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopAppt"
            android:background="@drawable/button_holo_sel"/>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand you have a huge 9-Patch as background.

AFAIK, 9-Patch can be extended but not reduced. So you probably have to edit your 9-Patch to make it as small as possible. Usually you can reduce the center-strechable area to one pixel.

Comment: Yep that was it , I didn't know Android did not reduce 9 patch images

Answer (score 0):

Here you declare button **layout_width as wrap** content so it takes width as image you set in background.

```
wrap_content
```

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown. For layout elements it will resize the layout to fit the controls / layouts added as its children.

so to overcome this problem use always nine patch images to background or change the layout_width in dp. (e.g 100dp)

Comment: Not sure I understand what your answer. I do have my image as a nine patch. There is text on the button and the button should resize to just larger than the text. I do not want to set the height / width explicitly because then I have to do that for all my buttons.

Comment: use small width nine patch image.

Comment: what is "small width nine patch image"?